# Dúvida - UPDATE MYSQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso fazer o update no banco mysql mas não consigo.

Basicamente estou seguindo os seguintes passos:

- pego variáveis do banco que são semelhantes a um determinado CPF e **exibo** 2 pessoas
- O usuário irá clicar em um botão para selecionar 1 pessoa
- Assim que o usuário clicar nesse botão eu preciso fazer 1 update em 1 campo da tabela.

Tem como?

Código:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<?php



    $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") 
    or die("Erro na conexão com banco de dados");      
    $select_db = mysqli_select_db($conexao,"mentoria"); 
    $campos = array(".", "-");      

    if(isset($_FILES['foto'])){ 
    $extensao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['foto']['name'], -4));
    $novo_nome = md5(time()). $extensao;
    $diretorio = "imagem/";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], $diretorio.$novo_nome);
}

    $cpf = str_replace($campos,"",$_POST["inputCPF"]);

    $consulta_jovens = "SELECT jfoto,jnome,jfaixaetaria,jescolaridade,jhobby,jcomida,jmusica,jesporte,jtime,jcaracteristica,janimal,jlivro,jsonho, ((CASE WHEN jovem.jfaixaetaria = mentor.mfaixaetaria THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jescolaridade = mentor.mescolaridade THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jhobby = mentor.mhobby THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jcomida = mentor.mcomida THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jmusica = mentor.mcomida THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jesporte = mentor.mesporte THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jtime = mentor.mtime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jcaracteristica = mentor.mcaracteristica THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.janimal = mentor.manimal THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jlivro = mentor.mlivro THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)+(CASE WHEN jovem.jsonho = mentor.msonho THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS qtdCaracteristicasIguais FROM jovem INNER JOIN mentor ON jovem.jcidade = mentor.mcidade AND jovem.jestado = mentor.mestado WHERE mentor.mcidade = jovem.jcidade AND mentor.mestado   = jovem.jestado AND mentor.CPF ='$cpf' and jselecionado IS null ORDER BY qtdCaracteristicasIguais DESC LIMIT 2";

    $string_sql = "SELECT * FROM mentor WHERE CPF='$cpf'";      

    $result= mysqli_query($conexao, $string_sql); 

    $resultadojovens = mysqli_query($conexao,$consulta_jovens);

    $dado = mysqli_fetch_array($result);    


    $nome = $dado['mnome']; 




    if(mysqli_affected_rows($conexao)){ 


        echo "<p><h2>Olá, $nome! <br><br> Escolha o seu mentorando abaixo:</h2></p>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p></p>";
        while ($aluno = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadojovens)){


        echo '<form id="formSelecionar" action="selecao.php" name="formSelecionar" method="post"><div  style="position: relative; float: left; margin: .5%; width: 25%; margin-left: 10%;"><div style="width:250px; height:250px;"><img style="width:70%" src=imagem/'.($aluno['jfoto']).'></div>'."<br />" .'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Nome: </b>'.$aluno['jnome']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Faixa Etária: </b> '.$aluno['jfaixaetaria']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Escolaridade: </b> '.$aluno['jescolaridade']."<br />" .'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Hobby: </b>'.$aluno['jhobby']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span> <b>Comida: </b>'.$aluno['jcomida']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Estilo Musical: </b>'.$aluno['jmusica']."<br />" .'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sunglasses" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span> <b>Esporte: </b>'.$aluno['jesporte']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span> <b>Time de Futebol:</b> '.$aluno['jtime']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Caracteristica:</b> '.$aluno['jcaracteristica']."<br />" .'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-knight" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Animal favorito: </b>'.$aluno['janimal']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Livro: </b>'.$aluno['jlivro']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Sonho: </b>'.$aluno['jsonho']."<br /> <br />".'<input type="hidden" name="id_atualizacao" value="Id da linha a ser alterada"><input type="submit"  value="Selecionar esse jovem" class="btn btn-primary" name="selecionar"/><br /> <br /><br /></div></form>' ; 
    }


    } else {
        echo mysqli_errno($conexao) . ": " . mysqli_error($conexao) . "\n";
    }


    mysqli_close($conexao); 
?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Poste o código que você está usando

Comment: Postado........

Comment: Importante explicar o problema exato, de maneira mais objetiva. Ajudaria muito se colasse as últimas linhas do histórico (arquivo log) de erros do PHP para vermos que erro ocorre de fato, e descrever em quais laços e condições efetivamente o script está entrando.

Comment: Bacco, não tem erro...

Eu tenho uma série de informações que vem do banco, e dou a opção do usuário escolher uma... quando o usuário clicar no botão eu queria fazer o update na tabela. Queria saber se tem alguma forma de fazer isso...

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi seria da seguinte forma:

Você pega o CPF e pesquisa, conforme passou:

```
$string_sql = "SELECT * FROM mentor WHERE CPF='$cpf'";
```

Depois você gera o seu `form` aqui:

```
while ($aluno = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadojovens)){


        echo '<form id="formSelecionar" action="selecao.php" name="formSelecionar" method="post"><div  style="position: relative; float: left; margin: .5%; width: 25%; margin-left: 10%;"><div style="width:250px; height:250px;"><img style="width:70%" src=imagem/'.($aluno['jfoto']).'></div>'."<br />" .'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Nome: </b>'.$aluno['jnome']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Faixa Etária: </b> '.$aluno['jfaixaetaria']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-education" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Escolaridade: </b> '.$aluno['jescolaridade']."<br />" .'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Hobby: </b>'.$aluno['jhobby']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span> <b>Comida: </b>'.$aluno['jcomida']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Estilo Musical: </b>'.$aluno['jmusica']."<br />" .'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sunglasses" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span> <b>Esporte: </b>'.$aluno['jesporte']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span> <b>Time de Futebol:</b> '.$aluno['jtime']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Caracteristica:</b> '.$aluno['jcaracteristica']."<br />" .'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-knight" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Animal favorito: </b>'.$aluno['janimal']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Livro: </b>'.$aluno['jlivro']."<br />".'<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud" style="margin-right: 5px;"></span><b>Sonho: </b>'.$aluno['jsonho']."<br /> <br />".'<input type="hidden" name="id_atualizacao" value="Id da linha a ser alterada"><input type="submit"  value="Selecionar esse jovem" class="btn btn-primary" name="selecionar"/><br /> <br /><br /></div></form>' ; 
    }
```

Mas ao meu ver está errado, porque você está gerando 1 `form` para cada registro.

O correto seria você abrir o form, e fazer o `while` somente dos registros, e não 1 form para cada. Mas se for assim, ok, CONTANTO QUE: ao gerar o link no registro, você puxe a `chave primária` dos 2 registros, pois você precisa saber qual o registro que o usuário selecionou correto !?

Exemplo (não específico com seu código):

```
?>
<form>
  <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    <th>Ação</th> 
  </tr>
<?
while ($aluno = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadojovens)){
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?$aluno['nome']?></td>
    <td><a href="script.php?id="<?$aluno['id']?>>Selecionar</a></td> 
  </tr>
<?
}
?>
</form>
```

Seguindo em diante, contando que seu form está ok, puxando os registros e sua chave primária, você vai usar essa chave para fazer seu `script` que irá filtrar e fazer o `update`.

Caso não entendi realmente sua dúvida, comente.

Comment: Olá!

Fiz da forma que você sugeriu, porém na hora de exibir ele não exibe nada... somente o que está dentro do "<th>" e na parte de exibir o nome do aluno não exibe... você sabe informar o porque??

Comment: @CarolinaPerrettiCabral eu usei exemplos, tem que fazer conforme suas variáveis, etc. Edite a resposta, e poste o código após a alteração para vermos.

Comment: Alterei para as minhas variaveis, só ele não reconhece o "While", só aparece 1 aluno e não aparece em tabela...